# Assign list of outputs from command executed remotely via ssh to a variable in shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to connect to a Linux server and execute some commands. Below is the code snippet for it and the output.  I want to assign the output of 'ls' to a variable so that i can process it further. Let me know how to do it?

```
USERNAME=root
PASSWD=abc
HOST=1.2.3.4
SCRIPT="cd /tmp/sample/; ls"
cmd="ssh -l $USERNAME $HOST $SCRIPT"
$cmd
```

Output:  list the directories as below.

```
5
6
7
10
12
```

Comment: do you want to assign it to a variable in the remote server or in the local machine?

Comment: If you type that script at the shell, do you get the output you need?  Wouldn't you do better to replace the assignment to `cmd=` with either an array assignment or with direct execution?  Can you not simply use `output=$(ssh -l $USERNAME $HOST "$SCRIPT")`?

Comment: I am running it locally and getting the result from remote server. I want to assign the output(list of directories) to a variable and find out the directory which has the highest number and go into it and get some files. These directories will always have number and wont have any characters or string.

Answer (score 1):

You [shouldn't be parsing ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

If you really need to do this [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) with bash is one option. Note that the solution below does not store `ls` output in a single variable, it processes the output line by line

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
USERNAME=******
PASSWD=********
HOST=127.0.0.1
SCRIPT="cd /tmp/; ls"
cmd="ssh -l $USERNAME $HOST $SCRIPT"
while IFS= read -r line 
do
    echo "$line"
done<  <($cmd)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't neat for me:

```
SCRIPT="cd /tmp/sample/; ls"
cmd="ssh -l $USERNAME $HOST $SCRIPT"
```

Mixing local and remote commands like that could sometimes lead to misinterpretation.

If you could use bash, the better way to do it is to use arrays:

```
SCRIPT="cd /tmp/sample/; ls"
CMD=(ssh -l "$USERNAME" "$HOST" "$SCRIPT")
OUTPUT=$("${CMD[@]}")
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

If you like you could save the output as an array of lines instead:

```
SCRIPT="cd /tmp/sample/; ls"
CMD=(ssh -l "$USERNAME" "$HOST" "$SCRIPT")
readarray -t OUTPUT < <("${CMD[@]}")
for A in "${OUTPUT[@]}"; do
    echo "$A"
done
```

Additional note: `ls` is wise enough to detect if it has to populate files line by line or not depending on the output but some versions of it are not. If that's the case add the option `-1` to it.